# The value for annotation attribute PageableDefault.size must be a constant expression

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, pageable

I already went through many links but did not find solution. Here is my code:

```
@Value("${paging.default.pageSize}")
public int pageSize;
```

Controller method:

```
@GetMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Page<Employee>> getAllEmployee(@PageableDefault(size = pageSize) Pageable pageable) {
    return countryService.findAllCountries(pageParams, pageable);
}
```

> The value for annotation attribute PageableDefault.size must be a constant expression